# System almost halted by backgrounded `yes` command

Tags: process, kill

I recently ran:

```
yes Pandas > WantBamboo &
```

Though I didn't mean to put the `&` at the end... Something important then came up and I had to leave my computer for a couple of minutes, when I came back I found a file which is now several GBs in size and growing... With the word `Pandas` on every line!

My CPU cores are all at 100% and my RAM usage is going up too! I can't even open the System Monitor or a Terminal window in order to kill `yes`! And I don't want to just shut it down manually because that often causes some problems when I just force it to shut down manually...

So how can I kill it? Is there any way that I can just use a keyboard shortcut or something to restart everything without having to restart my computer?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: Are you NOT able to just use <Ctrl>-<Alt>-<F1>, and then **ps** and **kill** commands?

Comment: I had to look up the `yes` command - what purpose does this serve in real-life?

Comment: @david6: Everything had crashed to such a degree that it refused to open... I suspect its opening was just delayed by a million years though...

Comment: @CharlesGreen: I don't know... To take over filesystems with really large files perhaps? ;P

Comment: @CharlesGreen For example to auto answer prompts of programs / scripts / etc which don't have a built-in option to do that on their own. For example `apt-get -y install package` = `yes y | apt-get install package`.

Comment: @kos hmmmm.  I can see how that would work, I'm just not sure that I would want that to run on my system....

Comment: @CharlesGreen Well, for sure not how Paranoid Panda did that, there was [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257297/114435) question between the Hot Network Questions the other day... It's so fast it could quickly eat the storage.

Comment: @CharlesGreen it can be very useful for automation, where you want just to pipe a specific string into another command , because you know it's going to be asking same thing over and over again

Comment: @CharlesGreen http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/what-is-the-point-of-the-yes-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a computer starts misbehaving , use [Magic Sysrq keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key). Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SYSRQ</kbd> together, and press one by one, with a little delay after each, <kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>U</kbd>,<kbd>B</kbd> to reboot the system in a safe maner.

If even that fails - powering off will be the last resort

Comment: According to wikipedia there should be an `I` in-between the `E` and the `S`.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda um . . .yes . . .that's what i have in my answer ,too

Comment: Yes, now that @kos has added it in.

Comment: Oh . . .Well, like I always say - I'm an engineer , i don't spell well